# Drupal 7 – Hide menu item in specific block/region

Tags: drupal-7

I have two instances of main_menu on a page. One is in the header, using superfish. The other is in the sidebar, using menu_block.

I want to hide a menu item in the sidebar and show it in the header. Is this possible?

Could you use template.php to target a block/region?

For example:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['region'] == 'content' && $variables['block']->module == 'menu_block') {
    // What would go in here?  
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about template.php but you can go for `hook_block_view_alter` and change content as per requirement.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
function mymodule_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  if($block->title == 'myblocktitle') {
    $data['content']['#content'][idofthenodelink]['#access'] = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include some explanation to your answers, so that people could understand the solution, rather than copy-paste the routine and ask a similar question again next time